# C-variables won't be added

Tags: c, variables

I have started  learning C and I want to make an addition program.
I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main() {
    int a,b,c;
    scanf("Give a,b",&a,&b);
    c=a + b;
    printf("A+b=",c);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It is supposed to take 2 numbers from the users and show their sum.
However the only output I get after the user writes 2 numbers is `A+b=`
Any ideas?

Comment: I see no pressing need to ask this on Stack Overflow. If you don't know how to print variables, it just hasn't yet been covered in your course.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this surely will be covered in the next lesson.

Comment: `scanf` and `printf` need a formatted string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed to include a format specifier for your integer variable `c`. Without this `printf` doesn't know what arguments to expect following the format string, what their types are, or how they are to be printed. Change:

```
printf("A+b=",c);
```

to:

```
printf("A+b=%d",c);
```

Note that a good compiler with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) would have pointed out this simple mistake for you at compile-time.

---

Also your `scanf` usage is wrong - change:

```
scanf("Give a,b",&a,&b);
```

to:

```
printf("Give a,b");
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
```

Comment: may I ask what's the difference?

Comment: @cssGEEK: yes, one works and the other doesn't. ;-) Seriously though, read up on printf in your C book and understand how you specify the arguments that are going to follow the format string.

Comment: I don't have a book only youtube tytorials

Comment: OK - big mistake - without a decent C book you are just going to be programming by guesswork, which is a very bad way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `%d` conversion specifier in the `printf()` call:

```
printf("a+b=%d\n", c);
```

Without that, `printf()` doesn't know it's getting a second argument and won't do anything with it.

Of course, that `c` could just be `a + b`, there's no need to store the sum in a separate variable just to print it.

Also, you need specifiers in `scanf()`, it should be:

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

The first argument to `scanf()` is *not* a prompt that's printed, it's describing the expected input.

Last, you should check the return value of `scanf()` to make sure it's `2` before relying on `a` and `b` having valid values. I/O can fail, you need to make sure your program does the right thing if that happens.

Comment: also msising specifiers from `scanf`

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` is a function used to take in input from the user. You are expecting it to print something, ain't you? You need `printf` instead:

```
printf("Give a,b\n"); //\n at the end is good
```

Now, use `scanf` to scan in the input:

```
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
```

You are also missing the `%d` format specifier in the last `printf` as other answers have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**scanf() is an input C function** (scan with formatting) that **uses format specifiers** (%datatype  ex: %d or %i = int, which is what you want, or %c = char) **to store a data entry in given format**, provided by the stdin (keyboard buffer) up to and including a null (\0) termination char(in the case of a string);

The **Ampersand** (&) in C is **used to designate/return** the memory address (**where variable is stored**), as **opposed to the value of the variable**.

```
     scanf("Give a,b",&a,&b);
     c=a + b;
     printf("A+b=",c);
```

The **issue with above first line of code** is that you ***forgot to include the format specifiers*** (%d or %i would both work in this case, as I assume you are adding integers and not floats/etc).

Thus the solution to your first problem is an easy one:

```
     scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
```

Also, it seems that you are ***attempting to combine an input and output in one line***.
**Printf**, like scanf, **can use format specifiers, or** it can **contain only a string of characters**, and prints to the stdout (console).

What you want to do is **include a prompt asking the user for input** before storing said input. You **add the \n "newline" character** at the end to ensure to provide spacing between other outputs and inputs, among many other reasons when you get into char arrays[], aka strings. But for now, this should do the trick:

```
     printf("Give a,b\n");
     scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
```

Hope this helps both with the current assignment and with general/C programming concepts!